# C# using aggregate method on nopcommerce shipment items list not working

Tags: c#, list, aggregate, nopcommerce

Ok so I'm trying to get all items which have been shipped and add them to a list if the shipment item is not already in that list. But if the shipment item is found in the list then I want to combine those two items in the list.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var shippedItems = _orderService.GetOrderById(shipment.OrderId).Shipments.Where(x => x.ShippedDateUtc != null && x.OrderId == shipment.OrderId && x.Id != shipment.Id).ToList();

        List<ShipmentItem> shipmentItemsList = new List<ShipmentItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= shippedItems.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var si = shippedItems[i];

            var sii = si.ShipmentItems.ToList();

            foreach (var item in sii)
            {
                if (!shipmentItemsList.Contains(item))
                {
                    shipmentItemsList.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    var foundId = shipmentItemsList.Select(x => x.Id == item.Id);
                    shipmentItemsList.Aggregate((foundId, item) => foundId + item);
                }
            }
        }
```

For these two variables `(foundId, item)` i get errors:

> A local variable named `the variable name` cannot be declared in this
>   scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define
>   a local or parameter

UPDATE
I also thought I could try the following, but it's not joining the results.

```
if (i == 0)
{
    shipmentItemsList = si.ShipmentItems.ToList();
}
else
{
    shipmentItemsList.Concat(si.ShipmentItems.ToList());
}
```

Anyone able to point me on the right track.

Cheers

Comment: The reason you're getting a compiler error is because foundId was declared on the line above where you try to use it.  The bigger issue, however, is that you appear to be trying to use the Aggregate function to combine an Id (int maybe?) with a ShipmentItem and Aggregate works on arguments of the same type.  Additionally, I am going to guess that you have not defined a custom addition operator for the type.

Let's back up a second and talk about what the data looks like when you expect to hit the "else" and what you want it to look like when you're done. From there we can talk code.

Comment: @KyleBurns thanks for help :) Ok yeah that makes sense. Basically if an order comes in it can have many items, but all items might not be able to be shipped in one shipment. So multiple shipments are needed. So I want to get all shipment items so I can loop through each item, but if an item was shipped over two shippments(so quantity 2 in one, quantity 3 in another) it doesn't split them so it will become 1 item with 5 quantity. Kind of new to this so not sure how to go about it :/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification.  Essentially, the way that I understand your problem is that you need to take an object map that is grouped by Shipment and look at it from the point of Item instead.  Linq can deal with this for you by using SelectMany to flatten the list and the GroupBy to shape the flattened list into your new groupings.  I've made some assumptions about property names for the nopCommerce objects, but the following code sample should get you close enough to tweak with the correct property names:

```
var shipmentItemsList = shippedItems // This is logically grouped by shipment id
    .SelectMany(s => s.ShipmentItems) // First flatten the list
    .GroupBy(i => i.ItemId) // Now group it by item id
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ItemId = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(item => item.Quantity)
    }) // now get the quantity for each group
    .ToList();
```